# Speaker cabinet to improve sound of mobile phone loudspeaker (music)

Tags: acoustics

I want to experiment with an enclosure for my phone so the frequency response has a little more punch at the bottom end. I understand that something can't be created from nothing, but enclosures work for drivers so I can't see why not for the phone?

What sort of cabinet design would do the job? It would be nice if it preserved a natural mid and treble as well. Even if this design just dampens medium and high frequencies that would be fine too. The response without any enclosure seems to have started to tail off at about 260Hz and is almost gone by 130Hz. I can just about hear 60Hz if I put the volume on full and my ear against the speaker. (Don't try this on your hifi at home kids)

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, this is more of an engineering question, and thus off topic. Please read the [faq] before posting a question here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the frequency response has a little more punch at the bottom end

I think [this one](http://www.passdiy.com/pdf/KleinHorn.pdf) should do.  Of course, you'll only need one.

[image]

Comment: Was hoping for a speaker cabinet, not a fireplace